# Node.JS Unable to call a service running on localhost on different port

Tags: node.js, express

What i am trying to do is that that my application is running on localhost on port 3030
i have written this code

```
var request = require('request');

request("http://127.0.0.1:3000/showdb", function (error, response, body) {
    if(error)
        console.log("ERROR IS :"+error);

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log("body"+body) // Print the google web page.
        res.send(body);
    }
})
```

so i am calling another service of application running on port 3000 on my localhost.(127.0.0.1 default ip for localhost). But its not working  this request is never made and error outputs "Error: Parse Error".
My service of port 3030 is successfully called but in that service that request is never called. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the jason returned by this service ("/showdb")

result: [
 {
  name: "bridgevine",
  sizeOnDisk: 486539264,
  empty: false
 },
 {
  name: "crud",
  sizeOnDisk: 218103808,
  empty: false
 },
 {
  name: "exascaleDb",
  sizeOnDisk: 486539264,
  empty: false
 },
 {
  name: "local",
  sizeOnDisk: 83886080,
  empty: false
 },
 {
  name: "mydb",
  sizeOnDisk: 218103808,
  empty: false
 },
 {
  name: "test",
  sizeOnDisk: 218103808,
  empty: false
 },
 {
  name: "winedb",
  sizeOnDisk: 218103808,
  empty: false
 }
]

Comment: Are you sure that the service listening on port 3000 is actually run.

Comment: yes i am 100% sure it runs and returns jason data

Comment: You are outputting an error. Is there anything in the console?

Comment: here is it what console says                              "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" server.js
info: socket.io started
Connected To Mongo With Url: mongodb://127.0.0.1/exascaleDb
Server Started At Port 3030
192.168.100.4
POST /loadDataBase 25 ms 200
ERROR IS :Error: Parse Error

Comment: I don't understand the last two rows, but there is an error, which you should check. Anyway this error is from the console of the server running on port 3030. What about the one on 3000.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:3000/showdb this service is running on port 3000 if i call it in my browser it is successfully called and returns jason data   here is what consoles say                              "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" app.js
Express server listening on port 3000
GET /showdb dataBases 61ms - 643b
GET /showdb dataBases 63ms - 643b

Comment: Can you please post the exact json returned. I believe that there is the parse error.

Comment: I got the answer the data returned from /showdb was like this  res.send("dataBases",{result:result.databases}) so i changed it to res.send(result.databases) previously it was not proper jason format thanks for your co-operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suspect the parse error happens in either of these lines:

```
    console.log("body"+body) // Print the google web page.
    res.send(body);
```

Comment one or the other out.  Wrap body in JSON.stringify(body).  If this fixes, it means the 3000 server is sending JSON but you are acting like it is text.

Comment: The returned in body was not in proper jason format thats what cause the problem. I corrected the jason format and the problem was gone.