# Locally hosted NodeJS stalls when calling external web service

Tags: node.js, web-services, express

I have a route that calls an external web service (http://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/nfl-teams/json/test/), but whenever I call that route, it hangs for a good 90 seconds or more. Here's my route that I hit: http://localhost:3000/external/teams

I am using the `request` module via npm (`npm install request`). My issue seems similar to this SO question: [Node.JS Unable to call a service running on localhost on different port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586545/node-js-unable-to-call-a-service-running-on-localhost-on-different-port)

I've tried with both the chrome extension Postman and by entering the route directly into my browser, but both hang for a while and then close the request with no data returned. One thing to note is the browser never freezes, it just seems to be processing for a while. And an error is never returned either.

Here's my route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var request = require('request');

/* GET /players listing. */
router.get('/teams', function(req, res, next) {
    var result;

    request.get("http://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/nfl-teams/json/njrrdrk5f999/", function(err, res, body){
        if(!err){
            result = body;
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

    res.send(result);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Any idea why this never resolves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is wrong because it's doing the `res.send()` before the asynchronous request returns:

```
/* GET /players listing. */
router.get('/teams', function(req, res, next) {
    var result;

    request.get("http://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/nfl-teams/json/njrrdrk5f999/", function(err, res, body){
        if(!err){
            result = body;
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

    res.send(result);
});
```

You have to put the `res.send(result)` inside the callback and you have to name the 2nd argument to the `request.get()` call to have a different name than the `res` argument in the `router.get()` call so you can reach the first `res` argument to use it.

```
/* GET /players listing. */
router.get('/teams', function(req, res, next) {
    request.get("http://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/nfl-teams/json/njrrdrk5f999/", function(err, response, body){
        if(!err){
            res.send(body);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
            // should show some sort of response here
        }
    });
});
```

I'm not sure this explains a 30 second delay, but it would certainly be one reason why your original code does not work and could not work.

Comment: Makes sense. I was also getting an issue because of the conflicting `res` parameters since they had the same name. Switching the web service response name fixed this as well.